# What is getOptions in console command

Tags: laravel, symfony

I was working on creating a command and wanted to get all options, so I getOptions() in my code, but it always returned an empty array.

After doing some debugging, I found out that this getOptions method is defined in the HasParameters trait and is ALWAYS an empty array; I wonder what its purpose? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. Is that a Laravel thing? Or a Symfony one?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `getOptions` comes from [`HasParameters`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7c707a1f9e5cdb569f006702106324e3a8942e8e/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/HasParameters.php#L52-L55), and you should see that `HasParameters` is in `Illuminate\Console\Concerns` namespace, so it is 100% laarvel...

So, what you want to use is: [`$this->options()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7c707a1f9e5cdb569f006702106324e3a8942e8e/src/Illuminate/Console/Concerns/InteractsWithIO.php#L128-L131), it will return an array of options...

Answer (score 0):

When creating a command you can provide parameters:

```
protected $signature = 'app:test {user} {test=} {--force}';
```

this signature contains:

- arguments: user and test= ($this->argument('user') and $this->argument('test='))

  ex. `php artisan app:test 1 test=mail`
- options: force ($this->option('force'))

  ex. `php artisan app:test 1 test=mail --force`

separately, get all: $this->options() and $this->arguments()

*upd. as docs says:*

> The getArguments() and getOptions() methods are where you may define
> any arguments or options your command receives. Both of these methods
> return an array of commands, which are described by a list of array
> options.

actually, if you creates some command just forget about those functions